# SuperSet creating Filter for Array Colums

Tags: apache-superset

I have following query running in Superet

```
select items from item_table;
```

Result

```
[{item={departmentNumber=2, description=Guitar, itemNumber=563082}}] Array
```

I have done some calculations and created a dashboard based on above query.

Problem : I want to have a filter for `itemNumber` but in superset Filter Box it showing `Filters` as `item` i.e the array how i can create a filter using itemNumber

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to use each column and metric in Filter box. If you have nested JSON in your data set you must explode them to columns first before using as independent analytics in charts.